# How to enter Mailwizz cron jobs in Plesk?

Tags: cron, plesk

I have never entered mailwizz cron jobs to plesk so I am very confused.
I need to add following cronjobs:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/mangud.pw/httpdocs/kampaania/latest/apps/console/console.php send-campaigns >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Here you can see were the cron job has to be entered:

[image: Cronjob entry form]

I have tried different ways but till now it runs with errors.

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved the problem by using "Run a PHP script" and i have changed the command

**from :** ** * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/wizomail.xyz/httpdocs/apps/console/console.php send-campaigns >/dev/null 2>&1*

**To:** */var/www/vhosts/wizomail.xyz/httpdocs/apps/console/console.php* in script path
**and** *send-campaigns* as arguments

i m not a pro but i get result :) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RR7Op.png)